# Can't save value into database through Reactjs Component

Tags: reactjs, database

I just start learning Reactjs and I have trouble with Component. Here are my code:

```
export default function ChonLanguage() {
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState([]);
    const options = [
        { value: 'Vietnamese', label: 'Vietnamese' },
        { value: 'English', label: 'English' },
        { value: 'Chinese', label: 'Chinese' },
        { value: 'Japanese', label: 'Japanese' },
        { value: 'German', label: 'German' },
    ];
    
    const handleChangeOption = () => {
        return setSelectedOption;
    }
   
    return (
        <Select className={`col-12 o-languages`}
            onChange={handleChangeOption()}
            options={options} />
    )
}
```

It shown my options, but when I submit, I not save into Database. What should I change? Thanks

Comment: Please share Select component code and if possible share codesandbox link of same component in working.

Answer (score 0):

Made some minor changes to your code.

Kindly note:-

1. **setSelectedOption** is function of type **React.dispatch<[]>** which will update **selectedOption** state value so you need to pass some value in that.
2. **useEffect** is used to check the updated value of **selectedOption**, you may not use it.

```
export default function ChonLanguage() {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState([]);
  const options = [
    { value: "Vietnamese", label: "Vietnamese" },
    { value: "English", label: "English" },
    { value: "Chinese", label: "Chinese" },
    { value: "Japanese", label: "Japanese" },
    { value: "German", label: "German" }
  ];

  const handleChangeOption = (event) => {
    return setSelectedOption(event.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(selectedOption);
  }, [selectedOption]);

  return (
    <Select
      className={`col-12 o-languages`}
      onChange={(e) => {
        handleChangeOption(e);
      }}
      options={options}
    />
  );
}
```